# .NET Core application throws SSL connection exception while .NET 4.x does not

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, console, asmx

I have an application which calla an `.asmx` service over `https`. If I write this as a Console application with .NET 4.x it works perfectly. Both locally and on the server. But if I write it with .NET Core 3.1 or .NET Core 6.0 they work perfectly on my local machine under Visual Studio 2022 and via `.exe` file. But again when I deploy them on the server I get the following error.

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

Inner exception :

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
> transport stream.

I have confirmed that the remote server which hosts the `.asmx` service uses TLS 1.2, my server uses TLS 1.2 and I have added the following code in my application.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

Comment: What type server is failing?  The OS has to support the encryption algorithm in the certificate and the certificate has to be loaded on the server. Older server may not support new algorithms.  New server may be set to requires TLS 1.3.  See following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true

Comment: It is IIS 10.0 under Windows Server 2016. I have installed .NET Core 3.1 and 6.0 hosting bundles as well.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server?force_isolation=true#bkmk_sql

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However I have also investigated this site prior to upgrading our server to TLS 1.2. The subjects on this page unfortunately do not apply to my case. This is not a DB server and it is not Server 2012. I have used IISCrypto yo upgrade to TLS 1.2

Comment: The error indicates that the connection was closed and may not be TLS.  TLS is performed before the HTTP Request is sent and if TLS fails the request is never sent.  So if you get a HTTP Response with a status code than TLS is working.  Then the issue is Authentication.  You can use a sniffer like Wireshark or fiddler to see what is happening or Use Postman and see what Postman error give.

Comment: I tried to monitor traffic on Fiddler. The .NET code shows "ServerToClientBytes: 5719210" while .NET Core apps show "ServerToClientBytes: 0". IT seems that the traffic has not even initially started.

Comment: Check TLS packets, not HTTP,  You will see if you examine the packets that the version of TLS will be shown.  There is also a Certificate Block ii one of the TLS packets from server to client that contains the names of possible certificates.  The client looks up the names in the stores to find a matching certificate.  If no matching is found TLS fails.